# melted ice cream + iphone5s = my screen black & white bars

Tags: iphone

Combination of melted ice cream ,iphone 5s & someone sleeping on top of it all for an entire night. Now the screen looks like a retro jail house jump suit all black and white bars. I could think of a thousand ways to jimi rig it and know that none of them are any correct way. Need a positive solution. Phone still works as that it rings all the time and still powers up takes charge and powers down. Any one know what exactly and how to fix this probmlem. Or what needs to be replaced and best place to get a fix it my self kit? Thanks

---

What parts do i need to purchase to just fix it my self?

Comment: This article will help: http://www.imore.com/how-replace-broken-iphone-5-screen-under-10-minutes#slide2

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the screen. Take it to an Apple Store and have them replace your screen. You can also do that at any third-party shop.